# EJS-Maps: How to display a Route along a List of Locations (Long, Lat) with connecting lines

Tags: c#, .net, maps, syncfusion

I am working with EJS Maps on a MVC .NET Core project.
I have a List with around 30 locations, each with a longitude and latitude.

I need to display this series of points on the ejs map with lines connecting the points.
Kind of like a route on Gmaps, but it does not have to go along the roads.

Its just for visualization.

Does anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this with the maps control?

I do not want to overlay it with some weird js clutter that will be reloaded each time the map is moved a little.

Any ideas?

Thanks

I tried to find anything online on how to display lines between markers but couldn't find anything so far. I am in need of help.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the navigation lines concept, our Syncfusion Maps component can display lines connecting markers. To render navigation lines for markers in Maps, specify the location values as a latitude and longitude list in the "**latitude**" and "**longitude**" properties of the "**e-layersettings-navigationline**" tag. Please see the code snippet below for more information.

**Code Snippet:**

```
[Index.cshtml]
@{
    var latitude = new[] { 45.20963982924923, -14.9352284131176, 9.59098428152231, 61.322760583380074, -23.245005839827243 };
    var longitude = new[] { -108.83108343285129, -60.65563167966124, 19.04662953369177, 93.03887800340158, 133.72271880186048 };
    var tooltip = new MapsTooltipSettings
    {
        Visible = true,
        ValuePath = "name"
    };
}

<div>
    <ejs-maps id="maps">
       <e-maps-zoomsettings enable="true”></e-maps-zoomsettings>
        <e-maps-layers>
            <e-maps-layer layerType="OSM" urlTemplate=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/level/tileX/tileY.png>
                <e-layersettings-markers>
                    <e-layersettings-marker tooltipSettings="tooltip" visible="true" animationDuration="0" dataSource="ViewBag.markerdata" height="20" width="20"></e-layersettings-marker>
                </e-layersettings-markers>
                 <e-layersettings-navigationlines>
                    <e-layersettings-navigationline visible="true" color="black" angle="0" width="2" latitude="latitude" longitude="longitude">
                    </e-layersettings-navigationline>
                </e-layersettings-navigationlines>
            </e-maps-layer>
        </e-maps-layers>
    </ejs-maps>
</div>

 
[HomeController.cs]
 
public IActionResult Index()
{
   List<MarkerData> markerDataSource = new List<MarkerData>
   {
        new MarkerData { name = "Marker One",  latitude = 45.20963982924923, longitude=-108.83108343285129 },
        new MarkerData { name = "Marker Two",  latitude =  -14.9352284131176, longitude=-60.65563167966124 },
        new MarkerData { name = "Marker Three",  latitude = 9.59098428152231, longitude= 19.04662953369177 },
        new MarkerData { name = "Marker Four",  latitude =  61.322760583380074, longitude=93.03887800340158 },
        new MarkerData { name = "Marker Five",  latitude =  -23.245005839827243, longitude=133.72271880186048 },
};
ViewBag.markerdata = markerDataSource;
return View();
}
```

You can find the sample that demonstrates the same from the below link.

**Sample Link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/MapsCoreSample1104450592
[image: Display lines connecting markers]

**NOTE:** We have rendered a single navigation line in the above sample. You can render multiple lines by declaring multiple “**e-layersettings-navigationline**” tags.

Please find the documentation for further customization of markers and navigation lines from the below links.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/maps/markers#customization

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/maps/navigation-line#customization